# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created while using drawer

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I m using drawer list for my android application.
Got a issue.
When I click randomly (very fast) then I get forcestop and `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created` showing in Log.
I m using fragments

I m also getting the following Runtime error
at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:32

Here is a **part of my code** in selecting from drawer list and

```
Fragment home = new Home();
    Fragment feeds = new Feeds_ListView();
```

.....

```
private void selectItem(int position) 
{

    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    switch (position) 
    {

        case 0:
            setTitle(title[position]);
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, feeds);

            break;
        case 1:
            setTitle(title[position]);
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, NewPostFragment);
            break;
        case 2:
            setTitle(title[position]);
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, SearchDetailsFragment);
            break;
        case 3:
            setTitle(title[position]);
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, feeds1);
            break;
        case 4:
            setTitle(title[position]);
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, UserDetailsFragment);
            break;
        case 5:
            setTitle(title[position]);
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, FBActivity);
            break;
    }
    ft.commit();
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(title[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}


@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) 
{
    mTitle = title;
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}
```

Here is the part of Feeds_ListView();

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{   
    context=container.getContext();
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feeds_listview_layout, container, false);


    list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    mRelativeLayout=rootView.findViewById(R.id.mRelativeLayout);

    saveProgress =(ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.loadpost);
    saveProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);



    userAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.feeds_listview_item,userArray);





    mRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    list.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    list.setAdapter(userAdapter);
    return rootView;

}





@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{ 
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

     SharedPreferences settings =getActivity().getSharedPreferences("newdatabase",0);

        String user_id=settings.getString("user_id", "--");

        if(user_id.equals("--") || user_id.equals(""))
        {   FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();          

            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, FBActivity);
            ft.commit();
        }else{
                 new Onscrollasync().execute();

            ((PullToRefresh_Master) getListView()).setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() 
                {
                    new Onscrollasync().execute();
                }
            });
        }


}
```

Comment: Are you doing some operations in onCreateView before proper inflation? Move that code to onActivityCreated or onViewCreated .

Comment: show your Feeds_Listview fragment.class file

Comment: @goonerdroid i have added the code.. Please suggest.

Comment: After researching one week i got the solution, ' @Override
 public void onStop() {
     super.onStop();
     if (onsynk != null) {
      onsynk.cancel(true);
        }
 }
 '

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the code in the Fragment `Home` that you wrote in the `onCreateView`. Move the code in your `onCreateView()` to either `onActivityCreated()` or `onViewCreated()`. There are several similar question on StackOverlfow like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26351457/android-illegal-state-exception-content-view-not-yet-create).

Comment: Actually, i m not getting forcestop which i m clicking the drawer list in normal speed. but if i click the lists very very fast it gets forcestop... Hopefully this will help..

Answer (score 0):

Try  this instead of inflating a container,try to inflate your view without the container ie

```
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feeds_listview_layout,null);
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But i think moving my code to onActivityCreated() worked for my feed_view()

Comment: Oh no, again forcestop, when i click on drawerlist randomly

Comment: Did you pass the null parameter?

Comment: Yes. Null parameter forcestops at beginning.